# there is no join function in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I can use the join function in irb

```
irb(main):001:0> a='1/2/3'
=> "1/2/3"
irb(main):002:0> b=a.split('/')
=> ["1", "2", "3"]
irb(main):003:0> b.join('')
=> "123"
```

but in rails , the identical code will show me the error.

```
undefined method `join' for nil:NilClass
```

Do I miss or typo something, thanks

Comment: It's not that there's no `join`.  Whatever you're doing in Rails, `b` is not an array, but `nil`. This cannot be what you're doing in Rails.

Comment: Please post the actual code that's giving you the error.

Answer (score 1):

Rails is saying that you're trying to join a nil object, which is indeed not possible. You should check that your object is properly instantiated before trying to "join" it :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this (the whole code) in the rails console:

```
a='1/2/3'
b=a.split('/')
b.join('')
# => "123"
```